# Lisp match keywords and find values

Tags: lisp, elisp

Say I have a list with keywords:

```
'(("element1" :keyword1 "a" :keyword2 "b") 
  ("element2" :keyword3 "c" :keyword4 "d")
  ("element3" :keyword2 "e" :keyword4 "f"))
```

Which functions can I use to find which list elements contain `:keyword2` and find its value in each list? I'm trying to do this in Emacs Lisp but I think with the `cl` package I could possibly adapt a Common Lisp solution? I've tried to use the `find` function as illustrated [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/Lisp-Notes/Higher-Order.html) but to no avail (of course, after changing a few syntax elements to adapt the examples to Emacs Lisp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(require 'cl)

(defvar *data* '(("element1" :keyword1 "a" :keyword2 "b") 
                 ("element2" :keyword3 "c" :keyword4 "d")
                 ("element3" :keyword2 "e" :keyword4 "f")))

(find :keyword2 *data* :test #'find)
;;=> ("element1" :keyword1 "a" :keyword2 "b")

(getf (cdr (find :keyword2 *data* :test #'find)) :keyword2)
;;=> "b"

;; Above only finds the first match; to find all matches, 
;; use REMOVE* to remove elements that do not contain the keyword:

(remove* :keyword2 *data* :test-not #'find)
;;=> (("element1" :keyword1 "a" :keyword2 "b")
;;    ("element3" :keyword2 "e" :keyword4 "f"))

(mapcar (lambda (x) (getf (cdr x) :keyword2))
        (remove* :keyword2 *data* :test-not #'find))
;;=> ("b" "e")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Common Lisp, you would typically extract the values with destructuring-bind in this case, something like

```
(destructuring-bind (string &key keyword2 &allow-other-keys)
   '("element1" :keyword1 "a" :keyword2 "b")
  (list string keyword2))  ; or do anything with string and keyword2
```

should result in

```
("element1" "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

In lisp, you would typically use a so-called *associative list* (or *alist* for short). It has the following form:

```
  ((key1 . value1) (key2 . value2) (key3 . value3))
```

There are a number of functions designed to work with alists, including `assq` and `assoc`, which return the dotted-pair, or nil.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm working with a custom variable created by another package so I'm at the mercy of its specification at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Install [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library (the GitHub link contains instructions). It contains multitude of helpful functions to achieve any goal. Suppose, your list above is named `data`, then you could:

```
(--find-indices (-elem-indices :keyword2 it) data) ; => (0 2)

(--map (cadr (--drop-while (not (eq :keyword2 it)) it)) data) ; => ("b" nil "e")

(--map-indexed (cons it-index ; => ((0 . "b") (1) (2 . "e"))
                     (cadr (--drop-while (not (eq :keyword2 it)) it))) data)
```